# Use of 'rest in peace'

Tags: expressions

Can the expresssion *rest in peace* be used in a humourous and friendly way to say, *stop worrying*?

Comment: No, but if you were to say, "Rest assured, everything is going to be OK," your words might bring comfort to something who is worrying. Young people today say, "Chill," "Chill out," "Chillax" [chill + relax], or "Take a chill pill."  In other words, "Relax.  Stop being overheated and cool it [hence 'chill,' meaning to reduce your heatedness by cooling off].  Take a tranquilizer.  Calm down".  These expressions can be at least semi-humorous and semi-friendly.

Answer (score 3):

I have never heard that usage before and if someone said it to me, in that context, I would assume that English was not their first language.

I say no.

Answer (score 3):

No, ***Rest in peace*** is *always used in reference to a dead person*. See [TheFreeDictionary](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/rest+in+peace).

I have never heard it used in any other way.

As @rhetorician has said, you can use the expression ***rest assured*** to assure someone that *everything will be OK*. But that is not a humourous usage.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think it's possible, because it has an offensive connotation.

For example:

> "But Jennie, the least you could do is to give me your new cell phone number. Why have you changed phones, anyway?"
>
> Jennie: "Oh, rest in peace, please!"

#### #

An offensive phrase taken from "urbandictionary.com"

Very desperate exclamation when an annoying and extremely obnoxious person just won´t leave you alone.

> Girl: why won´t you just leave me alone?!? You are an ugly fuckwit.
>
> Man: You know you want it, baby.
>
> Girl: Rest in peace, please!

Comment: This is slightly better than saying "Oh, drop dead!" though.

Comment: I have never heard "rest in peace" used offensively. Can you document this?

Comment: I've never heard "rest in peace" used the way they are in your examples - and after checking out Urban Dictionary, (which isn't a very reliable source!), those examples were mostly downvoted.  It's not offensive, historically, it's used as a blessing for the dead.  "Rest in Peace, Elvis!"

Comment: "Rest in Peace, Elvis" is the standard way. I think we are trying to find out nonstandard forms to use the sentence.